# find maximums and filter first values

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I use argrelextrema to find maximum value in list

```
import  pandas as pd
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
import numpy as np
noise_filter = 3
numbers = pd.Series ([101.5,100,101.1,99,105,22,21,20, 19]).to_numpy()
res = argrelextrema(numbers, np.greater_equal, order = noise_filter, mode = 'clip')[0]
print (res)
```

In this example it returns

```
[0 4]
```

I want to filter indexes if they are less than noise_filter.
So 0 will be filtered.

How can I do it inside line

```
 res = argrelextrema(numbers, np.greater_equal, order = noise_filter, mode = 'clip')[0]
```

So it will look like

```
res = argrelextrema(numbers, np.greater_equal & (index > noise_filter), order = noise_filter, mode = 'clip')[0]
```

Simple desicion when I make slice of res

```
res = res[noise_filter:]
```

doesn't suits for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to filter everything below your noise_filter

```
filtered = [n for n in res if n > noise_filter]
```